# how to retrieve image from database using mysqli prepare?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, image-uploading

I'm trying to convert my codes to `mysqli` prepare and I'm having trouble retrieving my images from database for a particular data. Let say for example, `id 1` will post the image of it in tha same page.

Can you please check my codes guys?
I'm trying to view the image for a particular data. can you help me guys? thank you, this is my code:

This is the code in my form:

```
<form action="upload_photo.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="alert alert-info" role="alert"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user" aria-hidden="true"></span>&nbsp;&nbsp;Add/Update Photo</div>
        <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?= $id; ?>" />
        <input type="file" name="image"><br>
        <input type="submit" value="Upload Image" name="submit">
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-md-3">
            <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
            <img src="image_view.php?id=$id" alt="...">
            </a>
        </div>
            Updated Photo 
    </div>
</form>
```

This is the code for my php upload image:

```
<?php

include '../session.php';
require_once 'config.php';


if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    $imageName = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_FILES["image"]["name"]);
    $imageData = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, file_get_contents($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"]));
    $imageType = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_FILES["image"]["type"]);

        if (substr($imageType, 0,5) == "image") {
            $query = "UPDATE `crew_info` SET `image_name` = ?, `updated_photo` = ? WHERE `id` = ?";
            $stmt = mysqli_prepare($conn, $query);
            mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 'ssi', $imageName, $imageData, $_POST['id']);
            mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
            $id = $_POST['id'];

            header("Location: ../admin/view_all_info.php?id=$id");

        }

        else {

            echo "Image not Uploaded!";

        }

}

?>
```

This is the code for my retrieving the image but it does not working for me:

```
<?php

include '../session.php';
require_once 'config.php';

if (isset($_POST['id'])) {

    $id = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['id']);
    $query = "SELECT * FROM `crew_info` WHERE `id` = ?";
    $stmt = mysqli_prepare($conn, $query);
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 's', $_POST['id']);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
    mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $id, $first_name, $middle_name, $last_name, $age, $month, $day, $year, $birth_place, $gender, $martial_status, $religion, $nationality, $email_address, $address_1, $address_2, $course, $school_graduated, $remarks, $date_added, $crew_status, $image_name, $updated_photo);

    while (mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt)) {

        sprintf("%s", $updated_photo);
    }

    header("content-type: image/jpeg");
    sprintf("%s", $updated_photo);

}
else {
    echo "Bad";
}



?>
```

The image is uploading but I cannot retrieve it. Please help me guys thank you

Comment: Instead of storing the image in database, store only the image name.
At the time of showing the image give your image path/image_name (this image name should fetch from database like other field name)

Answer (score 0):

There are a few problems here:

1. In your html you use `<img src="image_view.php?id=$id" alt="...">`. This makes a GET request to the server, so you need `$_GET['id']` instead of `$_POST['id']` in the script where you output the image.
2. You should not use `mysqli_real_escape_string()` when you use a prepared statement, mysqli will take care of that when you execute the prepared statement.
   <strike>Additionaly, in the script where you use it to get the image, you are not sending the database connection as the first parameter, so that will make it fail as well.</strike> **Edit:** You don't seem to be using the escaped value so you can simply remove that line.

Apart from that you should probably:

- Store the image as a file in the file-system. If the content is not sensitive / protected, you can put it somewhere in the root of the web-server so that you can easily include a link to it. It will make database maintenance and backups a lot easier.
- Only get what you need when you display the image if you use the method you are using now. It will make your code easier to read and new columns will not introduce bugs when you just do:
  `SELECT updated_photo FROM crew_info WHERE id = ?`.

Comment: I changed the `$_POST['id']` to `$_GET['id']` and in my query i selected only the `$id` , `$image_name` , `$upload_photo` and im so sorry how to send the database connection in my php view photo?

Comment: @jessfernandez You should not be using `mysqli_real_escape_string()` and as you don't use the `$id` value after that, just remove that line.

Comment: yes i removed the `mysqli_real_escapte_string already` i have there the `<?php include 'config.php'; ?>`  that has the connection to database

Comment: `<?php include'config.php'; ?>` is the connection database right?